# List of OpenCL compliant CPU/GPU

Tags: cpu, opencl

How can I know which CPU can be programmed by OpenCL?
For example, the Pentium E5200.
Is there a way to know w/o running and querying it?

Comment: OpenCL is a driver based technology, you should refer to the manufacturer for any informations about this at any time, it's also possible that the brand will drop the support for specific devices in the future so it's important that you keep yourself up-to-date

Answer (score 27):

OpenCL compatibility can generally be determined by looking on the vendor's sites. AMD's APP SDK requires CPUs to support at least SSE2. They also have a list of currently supported ATI/AMD video cards.

The most official source is probably the Khronos conformance list:
http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opencl

For compatibility with the AMD APP SDK: http://developer.amd.com/gpu/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx

For the NVIDIA, anything that supports CUDA *should* support their implementation of OpenCL:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html

For compatibility with the Intel OpenCL SDK, look at:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-code-builder-release-notes

Comment: Vendors  can't claim OpenCL support for a device without passing   the OpenCL conformance tests. So the Khronos  Conforming list  is the most definitive.

Comment: Nvidia CUDA up to date devices doesn't support OpenCL anymore

Comment: @TripleS I can't see how this is true.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the list of conforming  OpenCL products from the Khronos site:

http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/

Answer (score 2):

You got Intel OpenCL too http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-opencl-sdk/ for windows right now.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the CPU, [AMD's SDK](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx) is supposed to work on x86 (even on Intel's x86), so that will cover most of your options.

And for the GPU, I think almost all cards made in the last couple of years should run OpenCL kernels. I don't have of a particular list.

EDIT: Looks like AMD removed the original SDK pages with no replacement. There are unofficial mirrors for [Windows](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/ATI-Stream-SDK.shtml) and [Linux](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nicehashsgminerv5viptools/files/APP%20SDK%20A%20Complete%20Development%20Platform), but I haven't tried them.

Comment: Link is Dead :(

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke I think AMD removed it without replacement. I added a couple alternative links that are referenced around the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more comment about Intel,  Now they do not only support OpenCL under windows, but also linux. But it is part of a commercial SDK see https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-media-server-studio.

Another alternative for OpenCL development under Linux is Beignet, an OpenCL source project maintain by Intel China.
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/

I have tested on linux and it works as per tutorial, however, the compiler they use is completely different from the one under the windows.