# OpenCL compliant DSP

Tags: signal-processing, opencl

On the Khronos website, OpenCL is said to be open to DSP. But when I look on the website of DSP making companies, like Texas Instrument, Freescale, NXP or Analog Devices, I can't find any mention about OpenCL.

So does anyone knows if a OpenCL compliant DSP exists?

Edit: As this question seems surprising, I add the reason why I asked it. From the [khronos.org](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) page:

"OpenCL 1.0 at a glance

OpenCL (Open Computing Language) is the first open, royalty-free standard for **general-purpose parallel programming of heterogeneous systems**. OpenCL provides a uniform programming environment for software developers to write efficient, portable code for high-performance compute servers, desktop computer systems and handheld devices using a diverse mix of multi-core CPUs, GPUs, Cell-type architectures **and other parallel processors such as DSPs**"

So I think it would be interesting to know if it's true, if DSPs, which are particulary suited for some complex calculations, can really be programmed using OpenCL.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438895/list-of-opencl-compliant-cpu-gpu

Comment: As far as i know OpenCL is supported by some GPU and CPU. Never heard about DSP.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to add **why** I find it's an interesting question.

Comment: I tend to agree with @hotpaw2's answer.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one: The SNU-Samsung OpenCL Framework is able to use Texas Instrument C64x DSPs. More infos here:

http://aces.snu.ac.kr/Center_for_Manycore_Programming/SNU-SAMSUNG_OpenCL_Framework.html

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCL spec seems to support using a chip that has one or more programmable GPU shader cores as an expensive DSP.  It does not appear that the spec makes many allowances for DSP chips that were not designed to support being used as a programmable GPU shader in a graphics pipeline.

Comment: Agree, DSP chips are rarely programmable, they are usually very narrow in functionality, and if they are they are expensive. GPU is rare example of comparably cheap, powerful and programmable DSP chip.

Comment: DSP are very efficient for complex calculation. It's their purpose, and it could be really interesting for some custom servers, especially if a common programming standard were available. Some DSPs are multicore and really fast. And I don't understand what you mean by expensive. Last generation of GPUs are usually not so cheap either. Question is the return of investment.

Comment: To clarify "expensive", for just a few units, a mid-range DSP dev kit (including compilers) is usually more expensive than a mid-range gamer's graphic card.  But DSP chips are far cheaper for manufacturing in very high volume.  OpenCL seems to target the former use case.

Comment: So, what you say is that DSP will increase development costs, but will lower production costs. Most projects could probably live with that...